# Mushy-firm pasta in soup ..... help?

Tags: pasta, soup

I need soup help.
I am unable to make a homemade soup with pasta.
If I make chicken noodle I have to add cooked noodles just before we eat it. Otherwise all my soups turn out like a goulash. The pasta absorbs all the water .

Today I cooked a very tasty, successful, tomato based, beef macaroni soup with zuchini.... o.m.g. yum! It did look like soup at one point. And I'm so glad I snuck a bowl while it was soup cuz I turned the burner off to let it cool, came back to goulash. No more soup. Ugh!

I've also failed at freezing left over homemade chicken noodle soup. The pasta turns to mush.

It sure tastes good. But not what I wanted
Help!?
Thanks guys!

Comment: I make homemade chicken noodle soup all the time.  I also freeze it regularly.  I've never had a problem with the noodles being mush but that may be for several reasons.  I use linguine noodles in my chicken noodle soup, add them last after all the other cooking is done and only heat them until they are just al dente.  I cool the soup in the refrigerator in a mason jar then freeze it in the same jar.  My husband really hates mushy noodles and I never have had a problem with this method.  Hope this helps you.  :)

Comment: Could it be the amount of pasta; have you tried adding less? Are you using egg noodles, or dry semolina pasta which doesn't have egg? That might make a difference.

Comment: There's another discussion on here about how commercial soups can put pasta in there, when it's horrible for home cooks ... and some research suggested it's acid which retards the breakdown of the pasta.  Your success w/ tomato soup might give us a clue as to how much acidity is needed.  See http://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/51629/67