# Does using wild rice in soup suck up all the broth if it is held after cooking?

Tags: broth

This is my experience with rice and pasta. I was wondering if wild rice is less ‘needy’ in this regard and would soak up less broth.

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/20858/67

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you many know wild rice isn't a type of rice but rather a grass. Your intuition is correct that wild rice absorbs a lot less liquid than white or brown rice. However, what you can normally buy is a mix of the two so this may not be the solution you would want to go with particularly since straight wild rice is harder to digest.

If you want rice or pasta to absorb less cook them separately and combine shortly before serving.